# Non scientific questions, which are (IMO) on-topic, but require original research to answer

Tags: discussion

The question in... er... question is here:

[Does Louis Vuitton burn all their unsold bags?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/does-louis-vuitton-burn-all-their-unsold-bags)

I find this question interesting, I believe it is on-topic as there is quite something to be skeptical about, but you wont find anything on scolars.google (or any scientific or other source) to confirm or deny.

The only way you could officially (and within the rules of this site) confirm or deny this belief is to get an official position from the company in question. I highly doubt that this information would be in any of their literature (eg, website FAQ's) and so they only way you could answer this is to ask the company directly to confirm or deny.

But wouldnt this come under "Original Research"? Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

> But wouldnt this come under "Original Research"?

No. Notable references not only include scientific publications and official statements. They *can* include well-researched news articles published in a respectable newspaper or journal, for instance.

Otherwise this site would shut down pretty quickly. Plenty of questions here don’t have an answer involving a scientific publication, nor do they need to.

Comment: But im not talking about "well-researched news articles published in a respectable newspaper or journal" - you *won't* find that in this case. You'll probably only get definitive proof by asking the company directly. Hence the "Original Research" point.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you find an article about it in a respectable newspaper? Similarly, the current answer actually gives a very authoritative answer (not a definitive one, but so what?)

Comment: If thats authorative then the bar has been significantly lowered. It just re-repeats the same legend without any sources whatsoever.

Comment: @Jamiec There’s no lowered bar. We expect *notable* sources and of course not all sources are of equal quality but that *never* meant that you can only quote those sources with the highest standards of quality (i.e. peer-reviewed scientific studies).

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic principles of scientific skepticism is Sagan's principle:

> Extraordinary claims need extraordinary evidence

We stand by this principle on Skeptics, in that we ask for (factual) evidence of sufficient authoritativeness to support answers.

But, what does this work *in practice*? In practice we use the SE platform and voting system to select the answers based on this principle. *If you find the evidence in an answer convincing, up vote it. Otherwise down vote or leave it*.

In short, we let the community decide whether the presented references are appropriate or not.